# qgis-mesh data (GRIB2) to geotiff

Tags: qgis, mesh

basically i am trying to get out the direction and magnitude information of the current (flow/movement of water) information layer of a grib weather data file - which is a mesh in qgis terminology. I was following the instrucionts in [Tutorial on using QGIS for marine data](http://marine.copernicus.eu/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/tutorial_on_using_qgis_for_marinedata-1.pdf). the tools used there need a raster dataset for u and v components of the current. so far i have found information of how to transfer grib2 to geotiff. but the GDAL / raster analysis / translate function from Processing Toolbox doesn't seem to support mesh-data as input type. is there a straigth forward way within qgis to convert mesh into raster? or is there a way to display a u / v information from mesh as a vector field ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [...] is there a way to display a u / v information from mesh as a vector field ?

Not exactly within QGIS, but yes. I am working with *grib2* files right now and I just found `degrib`, a really nice utility to extract grib information to vector files:

https://www.weather.gov/mdl/degrib_archive

[image: 1]

I exported messages #1 and #2, which are *UGRD* and *VGRD*, for the first period of time, to point shapefiles.

Once added as layers in QGIS, I converted them to geopackage and generated a virtual layer with the information contained in both.

[image: 2]

Then, I also exported the virtual layer to geopackage. These are the *grib2* and vector layer together.

[image: 3]

Finally, we can just rasterize the vector layer. Note that the step of merging the two vector layers would not be necessary if you want them rasterized.

[image: 4]

This is the information contained in the *u* component of the wind vectors, in a raster of one band rendered in pseudocolor:

[image: 5]

Comment: any idea how to proceed to make a mean for all winds within a month or a year? all the data i get is of 1 day forecast. https://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/ ?

Comment: @assayag.org - speeds & directions ? ... does it make sense to mean directions? i'd suggest a count or % of the 8 main directions instead where total = number of days with wind > xy knots (or even better based on hours..)

Comment: id just wanted to know "where does the wind come from", in general, most of the time.